# Проблема с импортом класса в Python Django

Tags: python, django

У меня есть два файла в одной и той же директории. Из одного в другой необходимо импортировать класс и создать объект этого класса.
Код класса

```py
class Product:
    def __init__(self, IdNo : int, name : str, category : str, brand: str, price : float, country : str):
        self.id=IdNo
        self.name=name
        self.category=category
        self.brand=brand
        self.price=price
        self.country=country
```

А вот создание объекта

```py
RolexES228 = Product(739, "Wr980gc pro", "самые не точные часы", "tuhi", 1, "Мавритания")
```

Что я мог сделать не так? Питон не ругается, VS Code ошибок не пишет, но при запуске Джанго-сервера выдаёт ошибку:

```
File "C:\Users\Acer Aspire ES 15\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
 

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Lessons\clock_store\clock_store\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pages.views import *
  File "C:\Lessons\clock_store\pages\views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from class_prod import Product
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'class_prod'
```

Comment: Получили ошибку ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'class_prod',  - означает, что Python не может найти файл с классом. Проверь, что файл class_prod.py действительно находится в той же директории, что и файл, в котором будете использовать класс

Comment: Он действительно находится именно там.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я поставил вместо
from class_prod import Product

from .class_prod import Product

Т. е. поставил точку в начале файла, откуда импортировал класс. Мне помогло.

Comment: Вот не знаю, почему, в чём дело?